# EditText listeners not fired when it is in dialog

Tags: android, dialog, listener, android-edittext

I created a custom-dialog in android that contains an EditText and a ListView. The list view onItemClickListener is fired correctly when I select any Item, but it is not the case with the listener of my EditText.

This is my code:

```
EditText filterEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View content = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
filterEditText = (EditText) content
        .findViewById(R.id.filterEditText);
filterEditText.addTextChangedListener(txtListener);

............


    TextWatcher txtListener = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {

            filterEditText.setText("text entered");
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 4):

I was about to delete the post, but I decided to put the solution in case anybody faces the same problem.

I solved it by moving my code from onCreate into the method in which I created the dialog:

```
public void createLocationsDialog() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    builder.setTitle("Choose a location");

    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    View content = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);

    ListView locationsList = (ListView) content
            .findViewById(R.id.locationsListView);
    filterEditText = (EditText) content
            .findViewById(R.id.filterEditText);

    ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            data.getName());
    locationsList.setAdapter(modeAdapter);

    builder.setView(content);

    locationsDialog = builder.create();

    locationsList.setOnItemClickListener(listItemClicked);
    filterEditText.addTextChangedListener(txtListener);

    locationsDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue but in a `DialogFragment`. To state it clearer, add your `TextChangedListener` _after_ you call `builder.create()`.